# No resource found with custom buildType from main project with library support

Tags: android, android-build-type

So, I have the following project structure:

I have my main project which holds some nice layouts.
I also have my library project, which has some colors, dimens values and so on.

**main project**

- debug buildType
- env1 buildType
- env2 buildType

**library project**

- debug buildType
- release buildType

Everything was working perfect before adding custom buildTypes: the main project had the layouts, where I used the res/drawables/colors from the library project.

After I added my custom buildTypes to my main project gradle I can't build the project anymore, saying no resource found with that name. Important, this only happens if I choose other then debug buildType. With debug it still works, but than I can't change between endspoints.

Could someone tell me, why the library project is failing to provide the resources (using debug configuration)?

Any possible solution?

What I would like to have:
final APK == any custom buildType + library debug buildType

What I am able to do now:
final APK == debug buildType + debug BuildType

please find the code from my main project's gradle:

```
`debug{
```

debuggable true; 
    testCoverageEnabled true;  
  //default values 
   resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp S1" 
     buildConfigField "String", "applicationName", '"MyApp S1"' 
    buildConfigField "String", "applicationVersion", '"4.0"' 
 }  
 ENV2 { 
initWith(buildTypes.debug)   
       applicationIdSuffix ‘.envtwo’ 
      versionNameSuffix “_ENV 2" 
 resValue "string", "app_name", “MyApp ENV2” 
      buildConfigField "String", "applicationName", '"MyApp ENV2”’ 
  } `

**error message:**

> /app/src/main/res/layout/failover_tutorial.xml
>
> Error:(1) No resource
>   found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value
>   '@color/manual_bg_color’).

where failover_tutorial.xml sits in the main project and the @color should come from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution which was the following:

1. click on the app module and go to module settings
2. on the left module list select 'app' and go to 'Dependencies' tab
3. look for your library project as a dependency
4. make sure the 'Scope' is NOT 'Debug compile', if it is then set to 'Compile'

By doing this, it will be compile with all of your buildTypes.